Typescript: Optional operator / confusion with null
Quite straight question on how to write clean code here. Assuming I have a property with a backing field:
get value(): string { return this._value; }
set value(v: string) { this._value = v; }
private _value?: string;

this code is invalid since _value is undefined by default. To I actually have to write
get value(): string | undefined { return this._value; }

each time? Is there no shorthand? Looks pretty creepy to me. If I now accept null values, too, I'd have to write
get value(): string | undefined | null { return this._value; }
set value(v: string | null) { this._value = v; }
private _value?: string | null;

every time. Nicer solution? Or is as it is?

I think that's the best you're gonna get. Unless you create some sort of type Optional<T> = T | null | undefined and then use Optional<string> instead of string.

What do you mean by "shorthand"? What do you want to achieve?

On a side note: I do understand the need for the undefined, but the additional null option kind of muddies the waters too much for me, and I wouldn't use it in my own code.

it's probably better to remove the undefined completely and initialize _value to null

Coming from C# the difference between null / undefined annoys me a bit anyway. But ... different language, different rules - OK for me.
Just switched my tsconfig to "strict": true and looking for best practices now to handle errors. So usually people just write it that way?

Initializing with null makes me initialize thousands of variables I don't initialize right now. Feels a bit like unneccessary allocation I don't need right now. And then every getter still was string | null. There is no optional marker for a getter, is there?

Why not just completely remove the return type of the method?
get value() { return this._value; }. I think this pretty standard.

One can simply always use undefined and never use null unless you really really have to. The only time I found myself using null is when dealing with third-party json data which have null values in it. That being said, null does have its own semantic meaning and someone can find it meaningful to use both. You can read this post for more insight.

But what is the end goal? You want a shorthand to do what? You seem to be saying that _value is allowed to be undefined, in which case string | undefined is correct type for it. But you also...don't want that? So what should happen if it's undefined which, again, you claim is allowed? If it's not allowed, then you have no problem. Right now it's a magic circle.

"So usually people just write it that way?" YES.

"If I now accept null values, too, I'd have to write" why would you want the value to be both possibly null and possibly undefined? I'm well aware these are possible values in JS. But why use both? Typically you want only one of them. Unless you work with some existing (and not well-designed) API.

Lib code I want to make as comfortable as possible. A value might be set or not. And in the TS world or not pretty often means null or undefined.

It very rarely makes a difference whether something was not set or set but to a "nothing". Usually this is handled by picking one of null or undefined and sticking to it. And typically, if for a conscious decision for a "nothing" value, null is picked. Although undefined is still acceptable - there is no universal rule. If you already have a getter, then it's as simple as doing get x() { return this._x ?? null } to eliminate the undefined path.

Unless consumers actually need to do if (obj.x === undefined) { /* do 1 */ } else if (obj.xx === null) { /* do 2 */ } else { /* do 3 */ } But the maximally comfortable code is if (obj.x == null} to handle both anyway because it's almost never worth trying to figure which of the two the value is. You usually want to know whether it's there or not. You have to be really sure the semantics meaningfully change.

This really feels like an opinion question to me, is there some objective answer possible? Is it just... fewer characters than | undefined or | undefined | null? Or is it that you look at different approaches and choose the one you like the most according to some subjective criteria? I could write an answer that says: ms/TS#14417 is what you want, but it's not part of the language, and so you'll need to pick a workaround.

Alternatively, you could use typeofthis._value to infer the type instead of writing out the union each time.
class T {
  get value(): typeof this._value {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(v: typeof this._value) {
    this._value = v;
  }
  private _value?: string | null;
}

TypeScript Playground
But I don't think its actually necessary to use explicit types here. At least not for this exact example. TypeScript can infer them itself. The following is just as good as the above in terms of type-safety.
class T {
  get value() {
    return this._value;
  }
  set value(v) {
    this._value = v;
  }
  private _value?: string | null;
}


Like the idea pretty much! Is this a common use-case? Or just a technical solution, no one would use in his own code? Sorry, a bit opinion-based maybe ...

I don't see a problem with doing it that way. typeof can be quite handy for inference and I would actually solve it that way in an application. But unless you're returning computed values in the getter you really don't need it at all.

In such case, I would prefer more to a type declaration.
type TValue = string | undefined | null;
get value(): TValue { return this._value; }
set value(v: TValue) { this._value = v; }
private _value: TValue;

If OK, I would even skip the return type.
get value() { return this._value; }
set value(v) { this._value = v; }
private _value: string | undefined | null;


Is there maybe a shorthand for "null | undefined"? If the language already offers an optional (?) operator it feels bad to make a custom generic type I wrap almost every value with.

The closest you can get for the shorthand should be still a new type type Nullish = null | undefined, such that private _value: string | Nullish;

@tris the ? for optional is different from someType | undefined. The optional means it might not exist. Which, if read as value, does give you undefined but is different from existing: obj = { a: undefined } is will produce undefined for obj.a and for obj.b. But only one of the two is there. Similarly foo(x?: strting | undefined) can be called as foo() or foo(undefined) allowing both but you then have different number of arguments. If you really are trying to make a distinction between null and undefined then there should be a distinction between exists or not
